# Ensure sensitive data is removed from response

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have some dtos returned by my API that have sensitive data fields like Createdby, CreatedDate, LastModifiedBy and LastModifiedDate. These fields should only be in the response if the user is authenticated and/or have allowed roles in his claims. My current running solution is to use my dto mappers that have a dependency on IUserIdentity (custom interface).

`UserDto` record

```cs
public record UserDto {
    public string? CreatedBy { get; init; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; init; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalProviderUserId { get; set; }
    public string? GivenName { get; set; }
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; init; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
}
```

`UserDtoMapper` class

```cs
public class UserDtoMapper : IUserDtoMapper {

    private readonly IUserIdentity _userIdentity;

    public UserDtoMapper(IUserIdentity userIdentity) {
        _userIdentity = userIdentity;
    }

    public UserDto ToDto(User user) => new() {
        CreatedBy = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.CreatedBy : null,
        CreatedDate = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.CreatedDate : null,
        Email = user.Email,
        ExternalProviderUserId = user.ExternalProviderUserId,
        GivenName = user.GivenName,
        Id = user.Id,
        LastModifiedBy = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.LastModifiedBy : null,
        LastModifiedDate = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.LastModifiedDate : null,
        Name = user.Name,
        Surname = user.Surname
    };

    public List<UserDto> ToDtos(IEnumerable<User> users) {
        return users.Select(o => ToDto(o)).ToList();
    }
}
```

It work as entended but I would like to have a global and easier way to set these fields as senstitive and let the api filter them if the user is not authenticed and/or doesn't have allowed roles in his claims. After searching online for many days and did try and error solutions, I finally comes with my own solution and hope to have feedbacks on potential issues I could have. It works great so far.

My solution is to use the Filters in ASP.NET Core and Reflection (C#).

I've created this custom attribute `SensitiveDataAttribute`

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SensitiveDataAttribute : Attribute {

    public SensitiveDataAttribute() {
        AllowedRoles = Array.Empty<string>();
    }

    public SensitiveDataAttribute(params string[] allowedRoles)
        : this((IEnumerable<string>)allowedRoles) { }

    public SensitiveDataAttribute(IEnumerable<string> allowedRoles) {
        if (allowedRoles == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(allowedRoles));
        }

        if (!allowedRoles.Any()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("At least one role must be specified.");
        }

        AllowedRoles = allowedRoles;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of allowed roles.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> AllowedRoles { get; }

    public Task<bool> IsValidAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user) {
        bool isUserAuthenticated = user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

        if (!isUserAuthenticated) {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        if (!AllowedRoles.Any()) {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        bool found = AllowedRoles.Any(r => user.IsInRole(r));
        return Task.FromResult(found);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        if (!AllowedRoles.Any()) {
            return $"{nameof(SensitiveDataAttribute)}:User must be authenticated";
        }

        string roles = string.Join("|", AllowedRoles);
        var stringValue = $"User must be authenticated and User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles:({roles})";
        return $"{nameof(SensitiveDataAttribute)}: {stringValue}";
    }
}
```

And created this action filter `SensitiveDataActionFilter`

```cs
public class SensitiveDataActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter {

    private readonly ILogger<SensitiveDataActionFilter> _logger;

    public SensitiveDataActionFilter(ILogger<SensitiveDataActionFilter> logger) {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext _, ActionExecutionDelegate next) {
        ActionExecutedContext executedContext = await next();

        if (executedContext.Exception != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (executedContext.Result is not OkObjectResult result) {
            return;
        }

        if (result.Value == null) {
            return;
        }

        _logger.LogDebug("Filtering action result sensitive data of type {Type} started.", result.Value.GetType());
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        if (result.Value is IEnumerable elements) {
            int index = 0;

            foreach (var element in elements) {
                await FilterResultAsync(executedContext, element, $"[{index++}].");
            }

            _logger.LogDebug("Filtering action result sensitive data of type {Type} finished in {Elapsed} ms.", result.Value.GetType(), stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return;
        }

        await FilterResultAsync(executedContext, result.Value, null);
        _logger.LogDebug("Filtering action result sensitive data of type {Type} finished in {Elapsed} ms.", result.Value.GetType(), stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private async Task FilterResultAsync(ActionExecutedContext context, object? source, string? propPath) {
        if (source == null) {
            return;
        }

        PropertyInfo[] properties = source.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance
                | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.GetMethod != null
                && p.GetMethod.IsPublic
                && p.GetMethod.IsStatic == false)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties) {
            if (propertyInfo == null) {
                continue;
            }

            object? propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(source);
            string propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
            string path = $"{propPath}{propertyName}";

            if (propertyValue == null) {
                _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path}: {Value}", path, propertyValue);
                continue;
            }

            SensitiveDataAttribute? sensitiveDataAttribute = propertyInfo
                .GetCustomAttribute<SensitiveDataAttribute>(true);

            if (sensitiveDataAttribute != null) {
                _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path} is sensitive: {Value}", path, propertyValue);

                bool isValid = await sensitiveDataAttribute.IsValidAsync(context.HttpContext.User);

                if (!isValid) {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path} to be cleared: {Reason}", path, sensitiveDataAttribute);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(source, default);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (propertyValue is DateTime or string) {
                _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path}: {Value}", path, propertyValue);
                continue;
            }

            if (propertyValue is IEnumerable elements) {
                int index = 0;

                foreach (var element in elements) {
                    await FilterResultAsync(context, element, $"{path}.[{index++}].");
                }

                continue;
            }

            _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path}: {Value}", path, propertyValue);
            await FilterResultAsync(context, propertyValue, $"{path}.");
        }
    }
}
```

And register the filter `SensitiveDataActionFilter` like this:

```cs
services.AddScoped<SensitiveDataActionFilter>();
services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.AddService<SensitiveDataActionFilter>())
```

And add the attribute `SensitiveDataAttribute` to sensitive field:

```cs
public record UserDto {
    [SensitiveData]
    public string? CreatedBy { get; init; }
    
    [SensitiveData]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; init; }
    
    public string? Email { get; set; }

    [SensitiveData("SYS_ADMIN")]
    public string? ExternalProviderUserId { get; set; }
    
    public string? GivenName { get; set; }
    
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    
    [SensitiveData]
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; init; }

    [SensitiveData]    
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; init; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Circular reference is one problem I have have with my code. I might need to have a max-depth setting somewhere. I had problem with `DateTime` and `string`. `Datetime` gave me a circular reference issue and I needed to check if `propertyValue` is `DateTime` then stopped to go deeper. I needed to do the same with `string` because `string` implements `IEnumerable`.

Any feedbacks is appreciated. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code works. The question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fair, I didn't know code review existed. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275045/ensure-sensitive-data-is-removed-from-response

Answer (score 0):

My main argument against this solution is that in case of a bug you're revealing too much information. From a security point of view it much better to structure code so that in case of a bug not enough information is returned.

Comment: Good argument but I could say the same for using a mapper too.